# Cannot build Caliburn.Micro solution

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm trying to build Caliburn Micro and its sample applications that I downloaded from GitHub.  I downloaded the code from [the repository](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro) and I'm following the [instructions](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/build) to open and build the Caliburn.Micro project.

However, when I open the solution in Visual Studio, all the projects fail to load and I get these errors

```
C:\Users\brubin\Desktop\Caliburn.Micro-master\src\Caliburn.Micro.Core\Caliburn.Micro.Core.csproj : error  : The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated. The path is not of a legal form.  C:\Users\brubin\.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.0.54\Sdk\Sdk.props

C:\Users\brubin\Desktop\Caliburn.Micro-master\src\Caliburn.Micro.Platform\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.csproj : error  : The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated. The path is not of a legal form.  C:\Users\brubin\.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.0.54\Sdk\Sdk.props

C:\Users\brubin\Desktop\Caliburn.Micro-master\src\Caliburn.Micro.Core.Tests\Caliburn.Micro.Core.Tests.csproj : error  : The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated. The path is not of a legal form.  C:\Users\brubin\.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.0.54\Sdk\Sdk.props

C:\Users\brubin\Desktop\Caliburn.Micro-master\src\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Tests\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Tests.csproj : error  : The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated. The path is not of a legal form.  C:\Users\brubin\.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.0.54\Sdk\Sdk.props
```

How do I fix this?  I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community.

Answer (score 1):

The problem doe not seem to be in your downloaded code, but in the `Sdk.props`

I suspect, but you should be able to find the exact location of those calls from the error log. The function `GetDirectoryName()` expects a valid path as input parameter. Perhaps you can try to feed it `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

By the way, this does not seem to be exactly related to Caliburn Micro.